# Windows 10 (Unique?) Volume Issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

I've done a lot of searching around various sites and Google dealing with this issue, but nothing I've found seems quite like what I'm dealing with.

Since switching to Windows 10 the (audio) volume occasionally ticks up or down one notch when pressing seemingly mostly random keys.  It's primarily noticeable when I'm in games that I use the number keys (not the numpad) but it's not even always those that cause it, but usually it is.  Sometimes WSAD will cause it, and others even, but typically the number keys. It may happen twice in fairly quick succession, or not for hours in between.  Maybe I should explain by example.

So, I'm in a game, or program of any kind, and am pushing keys going along doing my thing and then out of the blue pressing 2, for instance, will cause the volume indicator like I've changed the volume with the keyboard to pop up and show the volume having gone up or down 1 tick, sometimes 2. I'll change the volume manually and go on about by business and then have it happen again some random amount of time later.  It isn't a huge problem but it is starting to become a nuisance so I thought I'd try to ask about a solution.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro on a desktop computer.

Some things I've tried already..

I've tried using this keyboard on another computer and never noticed the issue.
I've tried wiggling the volume knob on the keyboard but it never seems to effect the volume when I don't mean for it to (I don't feel like the issue is related to the physical knob)
Pressing the usual suspect keys over and over for about a page worth of key presses doesn't seem to force it to happen.
The issue happens in various programs sporadically, not just a single app/game.  And, I've tried adjusting Windows volume settings to see if anything causes it to happen more or less often to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if more information is needed, please ask.

Edit:
The keyboard is a Razer Reclusa; fairly old I suppose but otherwise everything works great on it still.  Also, I don't have another keyboard handy that I can try with this computer but since I used this keyboard on another computer without noticing an issue I figured that pretty much answered the question of if it was something to do with the computer itself or not.  Also, I give the keyboard a pretty thorough (opened up) cleaning about once a year, but this has been going on longer than that.

Comment: Do you have anything like AutoHotkey installed, which could have a hotstring defined for the volume control?

Comment: I thought about that being something to look for. But, it seems weird that it would do it so rarely sometimes if it was something set specifically TO do that, you know?

Comment: Well, if the keyboard didn't have n-key rollover and you were using the keys quickly, somewhere along the way a sequence of keys and some ghost keys could... yeah, it's not very likely. Have you tried saving any macros you've created and reinstalling the keyboard drivers? Using a different USB port?

Comment: I've not tried a new USB port for the keyboard.  I have reinstalled the drivers a time or two now though.